# Replace all HASH keys with another key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I'm trying to replace all the keys inside a hash with another key, like this:

```
{
  name: 'Josh',
  surname: 'Simon',
  cars: [{
    name: 'Diablo',
    seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Raptor',
    seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Testarossa',
    seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
  }],
}
```

let's say I want to change the **cars** key to **people**, so I can achieve something like this

```
{
  name: 'Josh',
  surname: 'Simon',
  cars: [{
    name: 'Diablo',
    people: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Raptor',
    people: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
  },
  {
    name: 'Testarossa',
    people: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
  }],
}
```

can this be done somehow?

Comment: Do you wish to modify (mutate) the original has or create a hash with the desired properties whilst leaving the original hash unchanged? Please clarify with an edit. If you assign the original hash to a variable (e.g. `hash = { name: ... }`, as @mechnicov has done) readers could reference that variable in their answers and not have to reproduce the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable `hash` holds the hash given in the example, and that object is to be mutated, one can write the following.

```
hash[:cars].each { |h| h.transform_keys! { |k| k == :seats ? :people : k } }
  #=> [
  #    {
  #     :name=>"Diablo",
  #     :people=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #    },
  #    {
  #     :name=>"Raptor",
  #     :people=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #    },
  #    {
  #     :name=>"Testarossa",
  #     :people=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #    }
  #   ]
```

​so now

```
hash
  #=> {
  #    :name=>"Josh",
  #    :surname=>"Simon",
  #    :cars=>[
  #      {
  #       :name=>"Diablo",
  #       :people=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #      },
  #      {
  #       :name=>"Raptor",
  #       :people=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #      },
  #      {
  #       :name=>"Testarossa",
  #       :people=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #      } 
  #    ]
  #   }
```

See [Hash#transform_keys!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21).

---

If the hash is not to be mutated you could operate on a deep copy. One of doing that is to use the methods [Marshal::load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load) and [Marshal::dump](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump):

```
h = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))
  #=> {
  #    :name=>"Josh",
  #    :surname=>"Simon",
  #    :cars=>[
  #      {
  #       :name=>"Diablo",
  #       :seats=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #      },
  #      {
  #       :name=>"Raptor",
  #       :seats=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #      },
  #      {
  #        :name=>"Testarossa",
  #        :seats=>[{:name=>"Josh", :surname=>"Simon"}]
  #      }
  #    ]
  #   }
```

Note that if we alter `h` by writing, for example,

```
h[:name] = "Lola"
h[:cars][1][:seats][0] = "cats"
```

we may verify that `hash` is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete old key and assign that value to new one

```
hash =
  {
    name: 'Josh',
    surname: 'Simon',
    cars: [{
      name: 'Diablo',
      seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
    },
    {
      name: 'Raptor',
      seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
    },
    {
      name: 'Testarossa',
      seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
    }],
  }
```

```
hash[:cars].each { |h| h[:people] = h.delete(:seats) }
```

```
hash

# => {
#      name: 'Josh',
#      surname: 'Simon',
#      cars: [{
#        name: 'Diablo',
#        people: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
#      },
#      {
#        name: 'Raptor',
#        people: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
#      },
#      {
#        name: 'Testarossa',
#        people: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
#      }],
#    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
hash =
  {
    name: 'Josh',
    surname: 'Simon',
    cars: [{
      name: 'Diablo',
      seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
    },
    {
      name: 'Raptor',
      seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
    },
    {
      name: 'Testarossa',
      seats: [{ name: 'Josh', surname: 'Simon' }],
    }],
  }

hash[:cars].each { |record| record.store(:people, record.delete(:seats)) }
```